# Как запустить этот файл server.js в npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

у меня есть файл server.js , который запускает локальный сервер для просмотра фронтенда
а я забыл какой командой его запустить

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
 file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(80);

console.log('Server running on port 80');
```

командой `npm run-script server.js`
выдает ошибки

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "server.js"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: server.js
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\Desktop\nano\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете запустить его командой

```
node server.js
```

Comment: ага, спасибо, так точно